# Can i access static property of base class, using object of derived class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have multiple layers in which i have field UserToken , which i need through out the session. i am hitting WCF service and with each request i pass a UserToken in header. Instead of passing this header each time i am setting UserToken in my base class, so that i take token from that static field. i am constructing WPF application.

```
    public class A  // Base layer
    {
        static string token;
    }
    public class B : A // First Level layer
    {

    }

    public Class Main : B  // Second level layer
    {
       //Here i want to do something like ...
       new B().[get base class of it i.e. A and then access static property of A]
    }
```

i need this because i have multiple layers in my project and i don't want refer base layer to my 2nd level layer ? How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Make your static string public

Comment: f**k how i forget to make public  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare the static property in A as protected, and just access to it from any derived class as you would access any static property:

```
public class A  // Base layer
{
    protected static string token = "base class token";
}
public class B : A // First Level layer
{

}

public class Main : B  // Second level layer
{
   public string GetFromBase()
    {
        return A.token;
    }
}
```

Just a quick console example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Main().GetFromBase());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without access modifier, your variable is *private*.
If your make your token variable *public* then you can access it like this:

```
public class A
{
    public static string token;
}

// ...

public class Main : B
{
    public Main()
    {
        string token = A.token;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make your `token` filed (or property) public or protected, it is private now. Then simply do:

```
public class Main : B  // Second level layer
{
    // ...
    Console.WriteLine(B.token);
    // ...
}
```

You don't need an instance of a class to access its static fields.